# Segmentation Fault: Core dumped; std::deque

Tags: c++, list, templates, deque

for my class I had to implement a class "List" which uses std::deque to "model" the functionality of a List (dont ask me why). This class needs to be a template class.

I also read, if you use templates on classes, the seperation of the class in header and .cpp file is a bit different. So I implemented everything in the header file.

However if I instantiate an object of "List" and use the member function "ins" to append something to my List, it gives me the segmentation fault after compiling.

Heres my .h:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <deque>
#include <iostream>


template <typename T>
class List {

public:
List();
void del();
void ins(T x);
void adv();
void end();
void reset();
void setEnd();
T get();


private:
std::deque<T>deque;
T *pos;
int ptrPos = 0;
T element;
};

template <typename T>
List<T>::List(){};

template <typename T>
void List<T>::ins(T x){
    deque.push_back(x);
    *pos = x;
    ptrPos++;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::del(){
    deque.erase(ptrPos);
    *pos = deque.at(ptrPos);
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::adv(){
    ptrPos++;
    *pos = deque.at(ptrPos);
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::end(){
    if(ptrPos == deque.size()){
        std::cout << "Der Positionszeiger zeigt auf das Ende der Liste" << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "Der Positionszeiger zeigt NICHT auf das Ende der Liste" << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::setEnd(){
    ptrPos = deque.size();
    *pos = deque.at(ptrPos);
}

template <typename T>
T List<T>::get(){
   return deque.at(ptrPos); 
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::reset(){
    *pos = deque.at(1);
    ptrPos = 1;
}

#endif  /* LIST_H */
```

and my main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    List <int> ListInt;




    ListInt.ins(5);

    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any kind of help or constructive criticism.
Also if anything important is missing, dont hesitate to let me know.

Best regards,

Dethe

Comment: Get rid of `pos` and `ptrPos` and replace both by `deque::iterator`.

Comment: Well, did you step through your code using the debugger to narrow at which line the `SEGFAULT` actually occurs? That far for _"constructive criticism"_.

Comment: Can you run this under gdb and get a stacktrace? I think you're misusing the `pos` ptr through. `*pos = x` is trying to assign `x` to the what `pos` is pointing to. I think instead you want to use `pos = &x` which assigns the address of `x` to `pos`.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is with `*pos = x;` and not `std::deque`.  When you construct `ListInt` you use the default constructor which does not initialize `pos`.  When you do `*pos = x;` you dereference an uninitialized pointer which is undefined behavior and is causing the crash.

I am not sure what you a trying to use `pos` for but it doesn't look like you need a pointer at all.

Comment: Well, I dont know how to get the current position of the iterator of deque. I have to implement for example a function, which tells me if the iterator is at the end of my list. And also a function which moves the iterator of my list by i. Thats why I used another pointer and a counter, which tells me at which exact position my pointer is. I am a beginner, I dont know any better :/

Comment: @Dethe How do you have an end?  A `std::deque` can grown until you run out of memory.

Comment: by end I mean the last element of my deque

Comment: @Dethe You can get the position of the iterator by using `std::distance(deque.begin(), your_iterator);`  There is no need for `pos` if this is what you want to accomplish.